# How to filter list of filenames in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

is there any way to filter a list of file names in Makefile based on the condition that the file exist or not?

e.g. I have a list of names: "dir1/include" "dir2/include" "dir3/include" ("dir2/include" doesn't exists).

This list is created by addsuffix function

```
 #simplified version:
 define include_dir
    $(addsuffix /include , dir1 dir2 dir3)
 endef
```

I need to check if all these names actually exist and return a list of only existing files
from include_dir call

"dir1/include" "dir3/include"

what is the correct way of doing something like this?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) will return the path only if it exists.

So this macro will include only the existing directories :

```
define include_dir
    $(wildcard $(addsuffix /include , dir1 dir2 dir3))
endef
```

Comment: No need for `foreach` here, wildcard takes a [list of patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function).

Comment: @EtanReisner you're right `$(wildcard $(addsuffix /include , dir1 dir2 dir3))` do the job. I update the answer to improve it.